# Testing with Jest - HTML DOM function not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I came across this error:

> TypeError: document.querySelector is not a function

In this line:

```
selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectbox');
```

Basically just getting the selected element in a dropdown menu.

In my jest.config.js, I have declared document as a global:

```
  globals: {
    "window": {},
    "document": {}
  },
```

How come it is not seeing a function declared under `document`?

Also, for testing with jest, do we need to declare all functions as `export`?

Comment: Although `document` is defined, `querySelector` isn't and you are calling it like a function. What are you trying to test? Why are you creating a stub `document` on a NodeJS app?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

`main.js`:

```js
export function main() {
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectbox');
  return selectElement;
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from './main';

describe('59423508', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mElement = {};
    document.querySelector = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mElement);
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toEqual(mElement);
    expect(document.querySelector).toBeCalledWith('#selectbox');
  });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  globals: {
    window: {},
    document: {},
  },
};
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59423508/main.test.js (12.631s)
  59423508
    ✓ should pass (8ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.853s
```